# How to include a module in all of Rails project's ActiveRecord models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, module, polymorphism

I want to include this module in every ActiveRecord model in my Rails app, without dropping `include NotificationResourceableTraits` in each file. Is there a way?

```
module NotificationResourceableTraits
  def self.included(base)
    base.has_many :notification_resources, :as => :notification_resourceable
    base.has_many :notifications, :through => :notification_resources
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tackled this problem just recently.  Take a look at my Gist: http://gist.github.com/404298

You could simply do this:

```
ModelDiscovery.valid_active_record_classes.each do |model|
  model.include YourMixinModule
end
```

### Explanation

1. Get list of all files in 'app/models'
2. Convert filenames to CamelCase
3. Constantize all of them
4. Check if the tables exist (if you want)